# Python: ModuleNotFound error when file is in the same folder

Tags: python, pickle

I was trying to load a dataset with pickle, when this error popped up:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'treeUtil'
```

I was confused at first because I wasn't importing a module called treeUtil, but then I realized that the file I was loading was. I tried to re-organize the file with the dataset so that treeUtil was in the same folder as ibcData(the dataset), but it still didn't work, and gave me the same error. I'm pretty sure this is a misunderstanding of modules on my part, but here is my code:

```
import pickle, pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from zeugma.embeddings import EmbeddingTransformer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

class PoliticalBiasDetector():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None
        self.vectorizer = None
    
    def train(self):

        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["text","label"])
        [lib, con, neutral] = pickle.load(open('full_ibc/ibcData.pkl', 'rb'))

        for tree in lib:
            df = df.append({'text':tree.get_words(), 'label': "Liberal"})

        for tree in con:
            df = df.append({'text':tree.get_words(), 'label': "Conservative"})

        for tree in neutral:
            df = df.append({'text':tree.get_words(), 'label': "Neutral"})
        
        self.model = MLPClassifier()
        self.vectorizer = EmbeddingTransformer('glove')

        x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(df[text], df[label],test_size=0.2,shuffle=True)

        train = self.vectorizer.transform(x_train)
        test = self.vectorizer.transform(x_test)

        self.model.fit(train,y_train)
        y_predict = self.model.predict(test)
        score = accuracy_score(y_test,y_predict)

        print ('Program Log: Model has been trained on the dataset.')
        print ("The accuracy is:",round(score*100,2))
```

This is the picture of the file I'm trying to load from.[image: It clearly has treeUtil within the same file]

Comment: 1. Can you provide more info about what kind of file it is? 2. What does your folder structure look like?  3. Have you tried using the `traceback` library? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html   4. Have you tried using `pandas.read_pickle()` function to load the pickle file since you already have that library loaded?

Comment: what is your file called? and which portion of code calls for the module? can you reveal the structure of your project?

Comment: @MarkMoretto pandas.read_pickle() won't work because the text in the dataset is in a parse tree format.

Comment: @raviadhikari The file (dataset, I'm assuming) is called ibcData.pkl. It's in a folder called full_ibc.  I got the dataset from here: https://people.cs.umass.edu/~miyyer/ibc/index.html